# Running php code chunk in background

Tags: php, iphone, ios4, apple-push-notifications

I have a php script which is responsible for reading some request parameters from my iPhone app. Once I do some manipulations to it I save them in db and will need to send some push notification message using apple APNS. So currently its done like this in the code.

```
<?php
    $param1 = $_POST['param1'];
    $param2 = $_POST['param2'];

    //saving part here

    //push notifications
    $pushService = new PushService();
    $pushService -> init();
    $pushService -> push($param1, $param2);

    //json response
    echo json_encode(array($success, $dbsavedid);
?>
```

Problem occurs with the push part. Now it takes lot of time for this push notification code chunk to execute because the table has grown with lot of data. Hence the iPhone app waits too long for this to execute (to get the success response to iPhone).

Hence is there any way to make this push part asynchronous and send a response to iPhone side using the echo other than using a separate script for push notifications? Also note that I need to get some data from saved records as well to iPhone side. So I will need the output to reach the iPhone side.

Comment: How much records are we talking about in that table? If its not millions and millions then you might have some serious schema design issues there.
What is the "long time"? Are we talking about tens of seconds or based on your needs more than 500 msecs is considered long?

Comment: This takes time cos it takes time to connect to the APNS and send notifications. There are around 100-1000 records and it takes like 5-10 mins now to get the response. It worked perfectly initially but as the records count increases it has decrease the speed. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Comment: 5-10 mins???? I'd argue that running that code on the background is hiding the real issue: bad code/data structures. Sure, you can run the code on the background, and it'll work just fine, right up to the moment you'll put such a load on your server the whole thing just falls apart...

Comment: Its nothing complex out there. I just retrieve records from DB and call the APNS. For the APNS part it takes that delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual reasons for this is, my server provider has blocked port 2195 and port 2196 which is used by apple APNS. I believe once you allow it this will be fixed and should work like earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can force PHP to send a response by using the flush() function for example. (there might be other possibilities to accomplish too)
So what you have to do is write with echo to the output buffer when your db operations finished (these should be really fast if you have 100-1000 records) and right after call the flush() function. Your client should get a response right away.

Also see this link about flush() itself, because there might be other parameters of your enviroment which prevents your response in reaching the client side as soon as expected.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

```
<?php
$param1 = $_POST['param1'];
$param2 = $_POST['param2'];

//saving part here

//json response
echo json_encode(array($success, $dbsavedid);

//response should be sent right away, no need for wait on the pushservice operations
flush();

//push notifications
$pushService = new PushService();
$pushService -> init();
$pushService -> push($param1, $param2);
```

?>

Comment: I did try that using ob_flush() and flush() right after saving part where I added the json response also after that as well. Hence it is suppose to print the output and start push notifications. But it didn't work for me. Its suppose to work for browsers but not for my scenario. That's why I specifically add this question based on iPhone. May be this is because the iPhone maintain the ongoing interaction with the server and its waiting for server to complete it.

Comment: Yepp, should be possible to configure it either on the client or the serverside to receive the response after flush happened. Are you using NSURLConnection or something else on the client side?

Comment: I am using ASIHttpRequest. This is an old app developed 3 years ago.

Comment: Just found this one they mention that if you use it in the "queue way" you could have a requestDidReceiveResponseHeadersSelector callback which might be the same as NSURLConnection's didReceiveResponse.
The link is: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: Did you try it with ASINetworkQueue also? (yeah I'm constantly editing my comments)

Comment: Thanks. Ill add that and see whether it works. Im wondering whether there are any solutions from php end to make the last portion in the background.

Comment: First solution is flushing, my other suggestion would be to refactor it to have 2 separate requests (one for the db operations and the other for the long running tasks which can be executed async) but you mentioned explicitly in your question that you dont want to do that so you gotta figure out how to do it with flush. (It is definitely possible!)

Comment: Yup. Separate request means again will have the same thing. Cos if its long running again only thing I can do is to make the delegate of ASIHttpRequest to nil so that we dont rely on the response. But it will be executed in background. Just didnt want to do that.